# Populate JS object depending upon size of array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Writing following node js code to populate `state` object with values passed via command line:

The state object:

```
const state = {
    prop1: null,
    prop2: null,
    prop3: null,
    prop4: null,
    prop5: null,
}
```

command line args:

```
args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(" "),
```

command format:

```
?command prop1 prop2 prop3 prop4 prop5
```

code to populate args value to state.properties:

```
for (i in args) {
            state.i = args[i];
            logger.info("state.j:" + state.i)
            logger.info("i:" + args[i])
        }
```

What i want is `state.prop1` should get `prop1` (which is passed by `commandline`)
so basically, my state object becomes,
`state.prop1 = prop1,state.prop2 = prop2` and so on.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply reduce the arguments to an object literal

```
let params = process.argv.slice(2).reduce((a, b, i) => {
    a['state' + (i + 1)] = b;
    return a;
}, {});
console.log(params);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, I am new to JS :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way can be done by `Object#assign`. Without `for in` loop you can do just

```
let state = Object.assign({}, args);
```

This will copy properties from the `args` into the new object `{}` and assign the result to the `state` object.

**Updated**

```
Object.keys(state).forEach((key, index) => state[key] = args[index] || null)
```

Comment: But the property names in the state object will change, Value of state object becomes: `0=prop1, 1=prop2, 2=prop3, 3=prop4, 4=prop5`

Comment: What about the `assign` approach ?

Comment: About that only @Suren Srapyan

Answer (score 0):

```js
const state = {
    prop1: null,
    prop2: null,
    prop3: null,
    prop4: null,
    prop5: null,
}
const c = Object.keys(state);
args = ['df', 'cf', 'ef']
for (let i in c) {
    state[c[i]] = args[i]
}
console.log(state)
```